# Connect switches using SFP connectors or uplink

Tags: networking, hp, switch, redundancy

In our environment we have 2 server rooms. One is our primary server room where internet is comming in and where our main servers are located.

Then we have a secundary server room where our backup servers are located. In this room we also have a seperated rack where all patches and switches are located.

In the primary room we have one switch HP 1950 24 ports with SFP+ transceivers. in the secundary room we have 2 switches HP 1950 48 ports with SFP+ transceivers.

To connect both rooms and servers we connect 2 sfp+ of the primary room with the first switch of the secundary room. Then using an uplink we connect switch 2 with the one above in the secundary room.

But isn't it better to connect the 24 port switch from the primary room with both switches for redundancy instead of using an uplink?

Answer (score 0):

-for redundancy issues it's a good idea to make 2links between 2 hp switches in your primary and secondary sites.
-and in your second site you can also make 2 up-links in load-balance mode between sw1 and sw2(ether-channel).
Thanks.